# Track status when you update ECS service task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am programatically updating the task definition in ECS Service (service has one task) using the [update-service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html) api. What is the best way to track the status of this? The API returns immediately and does not wait for the update to complete. One way would be to continuously describe the tasks. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way?

It depends. But an alternative way could by creating dedicated **CI/CD pipeline** to update your service, especially you this happens regularly. This could be done with **AWS CodePipeline** with an example of:

- [Tutorial: Amazon ECS Standard Deployment with CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html)

Initial setup can be slow, especially if done for the first time, but once done, you can have a lot of benefits. They include:

- automated deployments
- notifications if deployment fails or succeeds
- clear history of all deployments, and more.

Comment: In my case, the ECS services are created dynamically and I need to deploy to all of them. Would the solution work for this use-case?

Comment: Also, is there a way to programatically track deployments?

Comment: @ishan3243 Hi. Why do you mean by "dynamically" creating a service? With CP you would also need to pull for its state in a loop. But if you would like to automate this, you could setup notofications with CP, which would trigger lambda depending on failure or success. So there are some ways of making it all fully automated.